# Problema nullpointer en el tabhost

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengoque hacer una app que tiene 2 tab con unos edittext y otra con 13 botones pero el tab host me da null pointer

logcat

```
2020-01-04 20:15:45.284 14433-14433/com.example.ej9 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ej9, PID: 14433
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ej9/com.example.ej9.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.TabHost$TabSpec android.widget.TabHost.newTabSpec(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1508)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.TabHost$TabSpec android.widget.TabHost.newTabSpec(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.ej9.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6720)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2673)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1508) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText et1;
private EditText et2;
private TextView tv3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    Resources res = getResources();
    TabHost tabs = findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();
   TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("mitab1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("TAB1 Suma");
    tabs.addTab(spec);
    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("mitab2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("TAB2 ScrollView");
    tabs.addTab(spec);
    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
    tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            Log.i("AndroidTabsDemo", "Pulsada pestaña: " + tabId);
        }
    });
}
public void sumar(View view) {
    String valor1 = et1.getText().toString();
    String valor2 = et2.getText().toString();
    int nro1 = Integer.parseInt(valor1);
    int nro2 = Integer.parseInt(valor2);
    int suma = nro1 + nro2;
    String resu = "La suma de " + valor1 + " y " + valor2 +
            " es: " + String.valueOf(suma);
    tv3.setText(resu);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para todos aquellos que os ocurra el fallo es el siguiente
Cuando declaras el tabhost en Android.R.... sobra el Android
queda asi el metodo

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et1 =  findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 =  findViewById(R.id.et2);
        tv3 =  findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        Resources res = getResources();
        TabHost tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tabs.setup();
       TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("mitab1");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("TAB1 Suma");
        tabs.addTab(spec);
        spec = tabs.newTabSpec("mitab2");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("TAB2 ScrollView");
        tabs.addTab(spec);
        tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
        tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        Log.i("AndroidTabsDemo", "Pulsada pestaña: " + tabId);
            }
        });
    }
```